# Access Animator From Parent's Script - setTrigger

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, collider

I have a file structure like:

```
- Ball (CircleCollider 2D + RigidBody 2D) (BallScript.cs) as parent
   - BallGraphics (image + animations) as child
- Pipe (BoxCollider2D + RigidBody2D)
```

With this structure the ball collides the pipe successfully. It also recognises the function `OnCollisionEnter2D` (prints log).

However, when I try to use the animator to change the state of the animation on collision, it doesn't work.

```
public class BallScript : MonoBehaviour { 
    Animator animator;

    void Start () {
       animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
        print ("A");      // prints

        animator.SetTrigger ("BallHit");  // if comment it out everything works, if not, error below..
    }
}
```

> There is no 'Animator' attached to the 'Ball' game object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably need to add a Animator to the game object 'Ball'. Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

Fair enough, but I have the ball states setup in the Animator on BallGraphics like:

[image] [image]

other way round (hit->idle):

[image]

What is my problem? I tried tweaking bits but no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can try GetComponentFromChild.

Comment: I couldn't use GetComponentFromChild but I used `animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();` instead. It works now (I mean doesn't crash), however now I started receiving another error: `'BallGFX' AnimationEvent has no function name specified!`

Comment: Check if there is an event added to animation. Looks like there is an event but its empty, there is no function attached. Maybe a missclick.

Comment: It was pretty small so i missed it. Cheers :)

Comment: Please delete this question, to help avoid the incredible clutter with the Unity3D tag.